# How to find all places where a prop is being passed into component?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I have a component that has a prop being passed in and conditionally renders another component.

I am not sure if this props is being used and want to check if I can remove this condition.

Is there a way to check this in VScode?

The code base is huge and searching the word gives me hundreds of results.

```
const MyComponent = ({ aProp }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      MyComponent
      {aProp ? (
        <>
          <AnotherComponent
            rateCount={aProp.count}
            labelText={aProp.label}
            onClick={aProp.onClick}
          />
        </>
      ) : null}
      {/* other markup here... */}
    </div>
  );
};
}
```

How can I find all instances of `aProp` being passed in to this component?